# bamboo FindBug Plugin don´t show statistics

Tags: findbugs, bamboo

I have some problems with `FindBug Plugin` in bamboo. I want to trying use FindBug Plugin in bamboo. My project is getted from SVN repository and built with `maven3`. I import plugin and set Miscellaneous in configuration  in default job question.

Where should Bamboo look for the FindBugs analysis output?

I set like FindBugs Output Directory as `"c:\fb_report\"`

what you can see on added image

[imageshack.us/photo/my-images/37/miscalleneous.png/](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/37/miscalleneous.png/)

I build he write this on console

```
 14-Nov-2011 10:38:11 Parsing test results...
14-Nov-2011 10:38:11 Finished task 'Maven 3.x'
14-Nov-2011 10:38:11 Running post build plugin 'NCover Results Collector'
14-Nov-2011 10:38:11 Running post build plugin 'Clover Results Collector'
14-Nov-2011 10:38:11 Running post build plugin 'Artifact Copier'
14-Nov-2011 10:38:11 Running post build plugin 'FindBugs Build Processor'
 14-Nov-2011 10:38:11 Running post build plugin 'Cleanup Build Processor'
14-Nov-2011 10:38:11 Finalising the build...
14-Nov-2011 10:38:11 Stopping timer.
14-Nov-2011 10:38:11 Build PROJECT1-PLAN-JOB1-1 completed.
14-Nov-2011 10:38:11 Running on server: post build plugin 'NCover Results Collector'
14-Nov-2011 10:38:11 Running on server: post build plugin 'Clover Delta Calculator'
14-Nov-2011 10:38:11 Running on server: post build plugin 'Build Hanging Detection Configuration'
14-Nov-2011 10:38:11 Running on server: post build plugin 'Maven Dependencies Postprocessor'
14-Nov-2011 10:38:11 Running on server: post build plugin 'FindBugs Server Build Processor'
 14-Nov-2011 10:38:11 All post build plugins have finished
14-Nov-2011 10:38:11 Generating build results summary...
14-Nov-2011 10:38:11 Saving build results to disk...
14-Nov-2011 10:38:11 Indexing build results...
14-Nov-2011 10:38:11 Finished building PROJECT1-PLAN-JOB1-1.
```

From this I thing then plugin has been runned in build process successfully. then If I go to  to default job and click on  tab findbugs he show me only one graph and nothing more statistics like is showed here:

https://studio.plugins.atlassian.com/wiki/display/BFIND/FindBugs+Plugin

and directory set in Miscellaneous for job is empty.

[imageshack.us/photo/my-images/402/findbugs.png/](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/402/findbugs.png/)

I testing this plugin on more builds about 30. and nothing was changed. And I try generate Reports in report tab and this  show me only one graph too.

[imageshack.us/photo/my-images/607/reports.png/](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/607/reports.png/)

I don't now what I doing bad.

Answer (score 2):

It is your Plan responsibility to generate FindBugs report file. The Bamboo FindBugs plugin only analyzes data in FindBugs report file.

Try adding this to your pom.xml:

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    ...
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
      <artifactId>findbugs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.5</version>
      <configuration>
        <xmlOutput>true</xmlOutput>
        <xmlOutputDirectory>target/findbugs</xmlOutputDirectory>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
    ...
  </plugins>
</build>
```

also you need to add `findbugs:findbugs` goal to your Maven task configuration.

Please check updated [plugin documentation](https://studio.plugins.atlassian.com/wiki/display/BFIND/FindBugs+Plugin) - it should contain more detailed information on this.